# Python classmethod with inheritance

Tags: python, inheritance, class-method

Could someone explain to me how to correctly use classmethod with inheritance in Python?
I need to create **two** classmethod methods:

> 1. to makefull-timeime employee.
> 2. to make a part-time employee in Employee class which is inhering from BaseEmployee.

Seem that I fully don't understand a concept:(

> Ok, so the question is how to properly create a classmethod and then
> how to create a fulltime employee?

Thanks

```
from datetime import datetime

class Error(Exception):

    """Base class for exception"""
    pass

class InvalidDateOfEmployment(Error):
    """Except bigger date then today and seniority more than 50 years"""
    pass

class Application:
    @staticmethod
    def main(self):
        name = input('Name: ')
        last_name = input('Last name: ')
        date_of_employement = datetime.strptime(input('Date of Employement (2022-03-02): '), '%Y.%m.%d')
        if Application.date_of_employment_validation(datetime.today(), date_of_employement):
            raise InvalidDateOfEmployment

        employee = BaseEmployee(name, last_name, date_of_employement)

    @staticmethod
    def date_of_employment_validation(today: datetime, date: datetime):
        diff = today - date
        diff_in_years = round(diff.days / 365.25)
        return 50 > diff_in_years > 0 #diff_in_years < 50 and diff_in_years > 0


class BaseEmployee:
    def __init__(self, name, last_name, date_of_employement):
        self.name = name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.date_of_employement = date_of_employement
        self.now = datetime.now()

    @property
    def employment_time(self):
        return (self.now - self.date_of_employement).days

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.employment_time < other.employment_time

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name, self.last_name, self.date_of_employement


class Employee(BaseEmployee):
    def __init__(self, bonus, type_of_employment, hour_pay_rate, name, last_name, date_of_employement):
        super().__init__(name, last_name, date_of_employement)
        self.bonus = bonus
        self.type_of_employment = type_of_employment
        self.hour_pay_rate = hour_pay_rate

    @classmethod
    def create_fulltime(cls, bonus, type_of_employment, hour_pay_rate):
        return cls(bonus, 160, hour_pay_rate)

    # @classmethod
    # def create_partime(cls, name, last_name, date_of_employement, bonus, hour_pay_rate):
    #     return cls(name, last_name, date_of_employement, bonus, hour_pay_rate, 80)

    def calculate_sallary(self):
        return self.hour_pay_rate * self.type_of_employment + self.bonus

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Application.main()

def test_sort_employees():
    #given
    a = BaseEmployee('A', 'A', datetime(2020, 12, 10))
    b = BaseEmployee('B', 'B', datetime(2020, 10, 10))
    employees = [a, b]

    #when
    sorted_employees = sorted(employees)

    #then
    assert sorted_employees[0] == a
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Ok, so the question is how to properly create a classmethod and then how to create an fulltime employee?

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
from datetime import datetime

class Employee:
    bonus = 1
    base_hpr = 300


    @classmethod
    @property
    def salary_bonus_multiplier(cls):
        return cls.bonus

    def __init__(self, name, last_name, date_of_employement, hour_pay_rate = base_hpr):
        self.name = name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.date_of_employement = date_of_employement
        self.hour_pay_rate = hour_pay_rate
        self.now = datetime.now()

    @property
    def employment_time(self):
        return (self.now - self.date_of_employement).days


    def calculate_sallary(self):
        return self.employment_time * self.hour_pay_rate * self.salary_bonus_multiplier


    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.employment_time < other.employment_time


    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name, self.last_name, self.date_of_employement

class HalfTimeEmployee(Employee): 
    bonus = 0.5

class FullTimeEmployee(Employee):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = HalfTimeEmployee('A', 'A', datetime(2020, 10, 10))
    b = FullTimeEmployee('B', 'B', datetime(2020, 10, 10))

    print(a.calculate_sallary(), b.calculate_sallary())
```

classmethod mean to use only class avaluable variables. 
Inheritance helps to change them in a particular case.